# New Folder button and shortcut does not work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I recently upgraded from Vista 32 bit to Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit, now when I open a folder there is a button on the top of Windows Explorer called **New Folder**, which you click to create a new folder.

However, whenever I click on it, nothing happens. Also, windows 7 has a keyboard shortcut to create a new folder (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>), but even that shortcut does not create a folder. The only way I can create a new folder is by right clicking, selecting **New**, and selecting **Folder**.

I am trying to figure out why the **New Folder** button and keyboard shortcut are not working. If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with focus. If you want create new folder via button or shortcut, your focus must be in folder/file list.

[image]