# Windows 7 -- I can ONLY create new folders with command prompt --

Tags: windows-7

I am very capable of going into my command prompt and typing in *mkdir FolderName* but this is very annoying when I am creating folders on the fly. Right now when I right click on the desktop (or in any folder) and go to the **new** option there is no **folder** option in the menu. Also when I am in a folder and click the **New folder** button, absolutely nothing happens. Like I said I am using Windows 7 and would like to know how I can go about troubleshooting this problem and eventually fixing it. Thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming and programmers tools related questions, not general operating system or computer support. For that, you should post your question to [su]. Voting to close as off topic. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create new folder from anywhere in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/76916/cant-create-new-folder-from-anywhere-in-windows-7), [No “New Folder” button in windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/425539/no-new-folder-button-in-windows-7), [New Folder button and shortcut does not work in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/77199/new-folder-button-and-shortcut-does-not-work-in-windows-7) etc.